# What causes this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a sudoku game for Android but I'm having an issue. The game compiles, but once you get to the game screen and press a button the game crashes.

I checked the logcat and these seems to be the errors:

```
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at org.example.fpsudoku.Button.findScreenV(Button.java:59)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at org.example.fpsudoku.Button.onCreate(Button.java:38)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at org.example.fpsudoku.Game.showButtonOrError(Game.java:181)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at org.example.fpsudoku.SudokuScreen.onTouchEvent(SudokuScreen.java:221)
05-04 09:07:41.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
```

and this is the code that seems to be the problem:

```
    findScreenV();

    for (int element : usesquare)
    {
        if (element != 0)
            buttons[element - 1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    setListeners();
}

private void findScreenV()
{
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttons[1] = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    buttons[2] = findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    buttons[3] = findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    buttons[4] = findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    buttons[5] = findViewById(R.id.button_5);
    buttons[6] = findViewById(R.id.button_6);
    buttons[7] = findViewById(R.id.button_7);
    buttons[8] = findViewById(R.id.button_8);
    buttons[9] = findViewById(R.id.button_9);
```

Comment: We miss two important things - what is the size of buttons array and what is the size of usesquare?

Answer (score 8):

Just a guess - array indexes are **zero** based. If you need 9 buttons, you'll do

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[9];
```

to create the array and

```
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
buttons[0] = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
buttons[1] = findViewById(R.id.button_2);
buttons[2] = findViewById(R.id.button_3);
buttons[3] = findViewById(R.id.button_4);
buttons[4] = findViewById(R.id.button_5);
buttons[5] = findViewById(R.id.button_6);
buttons[6] = findViewById(R.id.button_7);
buttons[7] = findViewById(R.id.button_8);
buttons[8] = findViewById(R.id.button_9);
```

to populate it. Addressing `buttons[9]` in my example *will definitly* create an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: where do you suggest i put that function in my file?

Comment: @rich - errr - the second snippet is a corrected copy from your source, just paste it back to your code (`findScreenV` method).

Answer (score 1):

if an array is of length 9 it means you can retrive arr[0] to arr[8],if you try to retrieve arr[9] which is not there you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

In Java when you create the array, at that time u need to give the fix size of that array.
like  Button[] buttons = new Button[9] and then create the object of that array, like buttons[0] = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
          Other wise use the arrayList as best solution.